# Why does Linux force package managers?

Tags: linux, package-management

I'm new to Linux and I still don't see enough benefit to package managers to understand how they have become so dominant.

For example:  say I've heard Emacs is amazing and I want to try it out. I go to the Ubuntu Software Center and search for Emacs.

I get 11 results, half of which looks like it has nothing to do with emacs or are in Dutch.  Then, there are 5 results that look plausible, all with barely any reviews and horrible documentation. So, I have no way of knowing which is the real Emacs or that it is what I want.

I say I guess I will use the command line. Here, again, I get 8 results. At least here 6 of them actually say emacs in the name but no way to know which is the real deal.

I understand that the lack of dependency problems and knowing it is correct for your operating system are great benefits.

But how is this better than going to a browser, searching for Emacs, finding the downloads page, clicking on the one for my operating system and letting it go.  That way I know it is what I want, can see it step through and have been to the developer's site so I have an idea how supported and documented the program is.

Package mangers offer some nice features, but I don't see that they do enough to have become basically the only way to get software on Linux.

Comment: I don't understand the question. How are package managers stopping you from "*going to a browser searching for Emacs finding the downloads page clicking on the one for my operating system and letting it go*"? If you think that's better, why not just do it?

Comment: Because it impossible to do that, if you go to their site, the downloads are all .deb files, same thing goes for chrome.  Instead of providing full executable to install the program and set up its files how and were it needs them it throws you back into the package manager.

Comment: Linux doesn't force you to use package managers. I've installed Linux without any package manager before. Ubuntu may strongly recommend a package manager, but even there, you still aren't forced.

Comment: I think you're just not looking very hard. You can download the source code with build/install instructions with ease for just about everything available as a package. And where you can't, that's the choice of the people who provide the packages, not the distribution or OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are package managers prevalent?  Because people don't like having to download the source for every program they want to run, the source for all of its dependencies ( both build time and run time ), and compile it all themselves ( which often involves working out differences in configuration settings, and patching the code itself to work right with the specific versions of the other packages you have ).  It is much nicer when someone else has compiled the program for you, its runtime dependencies, and the package manager figures out what it needs to download and install for you.

Another way of looking at it from a more Windows' centric position is to think of "dll hell".  On Windows, you download program A, and it uses library Z.  Program A's installer places a copy of library Z in your system directory.  You then download program B, which also uses library Z, but a slightly different version.  It replaces the copy of library Z in your system directory with its version.  But that version doesn't work right with program A, so it breaks.  Eliminating this kind of breakage, as well as eliminating the need for both programs to include a copy ( whether it is compatible or not ) is what package managers do.  They figure out what libraries each program needs, and installs the correct version(s), replacing older ones when they are compatible, and installing both if they are not.

Most windows software has taken the aproach of just including library Z with both programs, and installing it to their own private direcotry.  This stops the breakage, but means that downloading the two programs requires downloading the same library twice, and taking up more disk space, and more ram since they aren't sharing the library, which defeates the original purpose of having the common library in the first place.

Comment: That makes sense and I see the benefits of using the package manager to avoid that annoying redundancy and that's fantastic.  But how did that happen and become the mainstay instead of the windows way of doing it, especially as drive space gets cheaper and cheaper?  It seems to me that it adds in a level of complexity and spreads around information to solve a problem that windows has solved without that.

Comment: `Linux is far more diverse. Anyone can create their own distribution, and many individuals and groups have done so.` - Linux is not ONE Linux-version only, but a multitude of them. check [Image showing Debian decendants](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/69/DebianFamilyTree1210.svg), and the text behind [this link
about Ubuntu](https://nuwan600.wordpress.com/category/ubuntu/)

Comment: @Hannu, I didn't say otherwise.

Comment: @Hannu mf he didn't say otherwise dont pretend to be wise here.

Answer (score 3):

Finding one single precompiled binary that will work on your Linux
system, without using a package manager, is not usually feasible. There
are simply too many kinds of Linux out there.

On Windows, you can find a single precompiled binary that will work,
because Windows is controlled by a single corporation and thus it is
relatively monolithic and consistent. About the only thing that varies
from one Windows box to the next is the version of Windows it's running,
and perhaps the service packs.

But Linux is far more diverse. Anyone can create their own distribution,
and many individuals and groups have done so. There are hundreds of
them, ranging from the popular to the obscure; from general-purpose to
highly specialized. No one could possibly compile a binary that would
work with all of them.

Thus, package managers. The creators of a distribution, being intimately
familiar with the components of that distribution, package up the
software to work with those components. They set up the dependencies and
identify conflicts. They stand prepared to handle any problems that crop
up, as long as they crop up on their own distribution. They keep up with
upstream changes. They deal with bug reports stemming from their own
mistakes, and pass the rest upstream.

You don't *have* to use these services, of course. You can always
download the source tarball and compile it yourself. It's well worth
doing so, at least once, to gain some appreciation of the complexities
involved in packaging software. The maintainers do a lot of work to make
things easy for the end users. Don't devalue that work.

If you're having trouble finding the right package on Ubuntu, I suggest
you ask for help on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Don't install software that you downloaded from the internet before checking in your package manager to see if the same software is available from your distribution's default software repositories. Installing software from untrusted sources is the easiest way to hose your operating system.

Package managers in Linux are designed to resolve dependency issues automatically and to make selecting software as easy as possible. However it restricts the user's freedom of choice to provide only the latest versions of all software packages in the software repositories. In the case of Emacs you may see GNU Emacs 24 as well as some older versions of Emacs, but it is a safe choice to select the latest GUI version of Emacs and install that version. Typically a GUI version of a package will have a nice icon to the left of the package's description in the package manager to give you a visual cue that it is a GUI version.

Using the package manager is the best way for a new user to select packages for installation. Installing packages from the terminal gives the user many more options to choose from, but it might be confusing for a new user.

Since you are a new user, I also have some advice about using Emacs. Emacs has a few features that other text editors in my default software repositories don't have, and installing Emacs is the easiest way for me to get a text editor with these features. I normally use only two features that are unique to Emacs, so I use Emacs when I need to use these features, and a more user-friendly text editor otherwise. Emacs is very customizable, and I have customized my Emacs to make it easier to use for doing the tasks that I normally do in Emacs.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows applications are usually standalone, and work well by themselves.

Linux takes a different approach, it's a composition of many small applications that work together. So if you want to create a new one you can simply compose others, saving plenty of time and maintenance.

But that net of relationships requires a package manager to handle what to install.

Answer (score 0):

Another argument for package managers is the **additional security and quality barrier and measure** this adds.

Without a package manager **you need to**:

- **trust the download source**. There are fake websites and download hoster which add/install annoying or harmful 3rd party adware/crapware along with the desired software. For inexperienced users it is often not trivial to identify the official software manufacturers website.
- **check the compatibility with your OS version**. Also Windows develops and changes its API by times and there are tons of software which is not kept up-to-date to work fully-functional with newest Windows, or the other way round it looses compatibility with older Windows versions one might still use. As already mentioned, the much more fluent and diverse Linux distribution world adds significant weight to this argument.
- **trust/review in the software safety** i.e. it does not harm your system security or privacy or even break your system. Even widely known und used software might not be as innocent as one might think, sending usage data without asking, opening network ports, adding firewall exclusions via installer, using insecure transfer protocols and similar. Distribution maintainers review all software (and every release) they add to their repositories, add reasonable default configs, in case daemon/service sandboxing rules, AppArmor/SELinux rules where required etc.
- **trust/review the software benefit and promises** i.e. it adds the value that you expect or that its manufacturer tells it does. Without putting to much personal opinion inside, I just want to mention RAM/registry/system optimisers/cleaners here and AV/firewall software which tends to add such functionality, even toolbars and such. You will likely not find software in Linux distro repositories which does not really add a value without the risk to break your system.

When using the package manager for your repository you can be quite sure that you get the correct software which has been reviewed or explicitly build/configured to be fully compatible with your distro version, to not harm your security or privacy, at least with default settings, and to be a real benefit, holding its promises, without adding advertising or other unwanted side-features.

FOSS theoretically lowers some of the mentioned risks, as the code can be reviewed, which is btw done by a significant share by Linux distribution maintainers, when searching for ways of implementation or due to bug reports. That Linux distros often clearly differentiate between FOSS, non-free open-source and closed-source blobs, makes it much easier to consequently stay with FOSS software, where possible, when using package managers.